# Functions from Scipy, Blas, or Lapack that compute only upper triangular matrix

Tags: scipy, lapack, matrix-factorization, blas

My goal is to transform a matrix into **upper triangular** form in Python. I know the function `scipy.linalg.lu` will do LU decomposition and get **both** upper and lower triangular ones. I need to repeat this procedure several times. If there is functions from `Scipy`, `blas`, or `lapack` that compute only upper triangular matrix, the performance of my algorithm will be improved significantly.

Could you please suggest such functions? Thank you so much!

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: you want to get only $U$ from $A=LU$ factorization, while $L$ is discarded?

Comment: Hi @AntonMenshov, for a matrix `A`, I can get both `U, L` by `U, L = scipy.linalg.lu(A)[1: 3]`. I can get `U` by `U = scipy.linalg.lu(A)[2]`. Even I use the latter, i.e. `U = scipy.linalg.lu(A)[2]`, the function `scipy.linalg.lu` still computes `L`, which is unnecessary for me and takes more time. I meant to looking for a function that only **computes** `U`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are overestimating the overhead of computing `L`. There are zero extra operations needed; the only additional cost is writing to RAM some numbers that you have already computed anyway. The algorithms commonly used (in Lapack, for instance) to compute `U` also compute `L` along the way, and you'd save 0 flops by omitting it.

For instance, if you think about textbook Gaussian elimination, the entry $L_{ij}$ is the multiplier $L_{ij} = A_{ij}/A_{jj}$ that you use to eliminate the zero entry in position $i,j$ at step $j$.

If you are at the point where that memory write cost matters to you, you should probably have ditched Python long ago since it is a much higher performance hit just by itself; for instance Scipy uses various un-compressed formats and does un-necessary copies of various things with respect to Lapack.